# Connection Between Kendo and SQL Server in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to do CRUD operation using Kendo UI to show my data in a grid view.
I can read the data from my database with the following code in my controller (my tables are in SQL Server and connected through a connection string):

```
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class HeaderMenuController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public HeaderMenuController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public DataSourceResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return _unitOfWork.HeaderMenu.GetAll().ToDataSourceResult(request);
        }
    }
```

index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MSDACE.Models.HeaderViewModel>()
         .Name("grid")
         .Columns(columns =>
         {
             columns.Bound(product => product.HeaderMenuID).Width(100);
             columns.Bound(product => product.HeaderMenuName);
             columns.Bound(product => product.HeaderMenuDispOrder).Width(250);
             columns.Command(commands =>
             {
                 commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items.
             }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
         })
         .ToolBar(toolbar =>
         {
             toolbar.Create(); // The "create" command adds new data items.
             toolbar.Save(); // The "save" command saves the changed data items.
         })
         .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode.
         .DataSource(dataSource =>
             dataSource.Ajax()
               .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates.
               .Model(model =>
               {
                   model.Id(product => product.HeaderMenuID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                   model.Field(product => product.HeaderMenuID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable.
               })
               .Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "HeaderMenu")) // Action method invoked when the user saves a new data item.
               .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "HeaderMenu"))  // Action method invoked when the Grid needs data.
               .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "HeaderMenu"))  // Action method invoked when the user saves an updated data item.
               .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "HeaderMenu")) // Action method invoked when the user removes a data item.
         )
         .Pageable()
)
```

The problem is I can't the delete or create operations.

I have written the `GetAll`, `Remove`, `Get` and other functions, but my problem is to reflect in the Kendo Grid

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {

        IHeaderMenuRepository HeaderMenu { get; }

        void Save();

    }
```

IHeaderMenuRepository.cs

```
 public class HeaderMenuRepository : Repository<HeaderMenu>, IHeaderMenuRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public HeaderMenuRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetHeaderMenuList()
        {
            return _db.HeaderMenu.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = i.HeaderMenuName,
                Value = i.HeaderMenuID.ToString()
            });
        }

        public void Update(HeaderMenu headerMenu)
        {
            var objFrobDb = _db.HeaderMenu.FirstOrDefault(s => s.HeaderMenuID == headerMenu.HeaderMenuID);

            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuName = headerMenu.HeaderMenuName;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuDesc = headerMenu.HeaderMenuDesc;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuActive = headerMenu.HeaderMenuActive;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuDispOrder = headerMenu.HeaderMenuDispOrder;

            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

IRepository

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T Get(int id);

        IEnumerable<T> GetAll(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = null
            );

        T GetFirstOrDefault(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            string includeProperties = null
            );

        void Add(T entity);

        void Remove(int id);
        void Remove(T entity);
    }
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            HeaderMenu = new HeaderMenuRepository(_db);
        }

        public IHeaderMenuRepository HeaderMenu { get; private set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public T Get(int id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }
            //include properties will be comma seperated
            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }
            //include properties will be comma seperated
            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            T entityToRemove = dbSet.Find(id);
            Remove(entityToRemove);
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

    }
```

HeaderMenuRepository.cs

```
  public class HeaderMenuRepository : Repository<HeaderMenu>, IHeaderMenuRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public HeaderMenuRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetHeaderMenuList()
        {
            return _db.HeaderMenu.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = i.HeaderMenuName,
                Value = i.HeaderMenuID.ToString()
            });
        }

        public void Update(HeaderMenu headerMenu)
        {
            var objFrobDb = _db.HeaderMenu.FirstOrDefault(s => s.HeaderMenuID == headerMenu.HeaderMenuID);

            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuName = headerMenu.HeaderMenuName;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuDesc = headerMenu.HeaderMenuDesc;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuActive = headerMenu.HeaderMenuActive;
            objFrobDb.HeaderMenuDispOrder = headerMenu.HeaderMenuDispOrder;

            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<HeaderMenu> HeaderMenu { get; set; }


    }
```

The problem is I cant to the Delete, Create or Edit operation!

I Belive that I can not make the connection between the Kendo and my Database and have to implement something in my controller.

I try the Kendo.MVC examples but the problem are the northwind and sqllite the used!

Could please help me by this issue to implement the CRUD on Grid using the data in my sqlserver tables.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud

Comment: Show how your grid is being created and how the CRUDs are being specified.  Are you using [Grid HtmlHelper](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/overview) ?

Comment: @Richard I updated the question , you can find more details now in it

Comment: Great to see more info.  You say "can't do the Delete, Create or Edit operation".  Are you seeing any error messages ?  Does the browser console show any error messages ? Does the client do it's thing but no changes are occurring in the data base ? Is there a routing in effect ? If you set a VS break point in `Update` does the code execution get there ?